# Displaying another entity's form on a node

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to embed the edit form for a flag on my node (the full page view mode).

After some struggle, I finally figured out how to get the flagging form.  But once I have the form, how do I actually get it to display on the page?

```
function MYMODULE_node_view(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'MY_CONTENT_TYPE') {
    $flag = \Drupal::service('flag')->getFlagById('MY_FLAG_ID');
    $flagging_entity = \Drupal::service('flag')->getFlagging($flag, $node);
    $form = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')
      ->getFormObject('flagging', 'edit')
      ->setEntity($flagging_entity);
    $form_obtained = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
    // How do I actually show the form on the node?
```

I looked at [this question on rendering forms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182405/how-do-i-render-a-form) (which says use the `formBuilder` service, which I am already using). I assume I need to put the form in a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/render-api/render-arrays) but the documentation is not clear about how to do that.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module yet?

Comment: @leymannx That module doesn't support flag out of the box (only handles commerce stuff + entityreference), so I am stuck doing it in code either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm()` already returns a render array, see the [FormBuilder::getForm() documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormBuilder.php/function/FormBuilder::getForm/8.2.x).

To render the form, you just need to pass the results of *getForm()* to your $build array, then render it in your template.

In *hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()*:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  // ...
  $build['my_flagging_form'] = $form_obtained;
}
```

Then in your twig template:

```
{{ content.my_flagging_form }}
```

Or, if you're already rendering *content* in its entirety, you may not need to update your twig template at all.

As @4k4 noted in the comments, you can also add the appropriate meta data in [hook_entity_extra_field_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_extra_field_info/9.0.x) to make your flagging form addition configurable (reorderable, etc) on your node's Manage Display screen. See [Creating pseudo-fields in Drupal 8](https://www.webomelette.com/creating-pseudo-fields-drupal-8) for an example.

Comment: When using `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view` you don't need to print it in the twig template, it ends up in `{{ content }}` of the entity template automatically and you can provide the meta data to make it configurable in [hook_entity_extra_field_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_extra_field_info/9.0.x)

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you @4k4, I didn't realize it was that easy to do that with *hook_entity_extra_field_info()*. (And thanks for pointing out my incorrect twig example :) )

Comment: I wouldn't say it is incorrect, it works for twig templates in general, but then you would add the variable in a preprocess hook.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sonfd and @4k4 for the answer and comment, I was able to fix it with the following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view() for MYMODULE.
 */
function MYMODULE_node_view(array &$build, NodeInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'MY_CONTENT_YTPE') {
    if ($display->getComponent('my_flagging_form')) {
      $flag = \Drupal::service('flag')->getFlagById('MY_FLAG');
      $flagging_entity = \Drupal::service('flag')->getFlagging($flag, $node);
      $form = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')
        ->getFormObject('flagging', 'edit')
        ->setEntity($flagging_entity);
      $build['my_flagging_form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_extra_field_info() for MYMODULE.
 *
 * Https://www.webomelette.com/creating-pseudo-fields-drupal-8
 */
function MYMODULE_entity_extra_field_info() {
  $extra = [];

  $extra['node'][NodeType::load('MY_CONTENT_TYPE')->Id()]['display']['my_flagging_form'] = [
    'label' => t('My flagging edit form'),
    'description' => t('This shows the my flagging edit form.'),
    'weight' => 100,
    'visible' => TRUE,
  ];

  return $extra;
}
```